# How to join connecting flights from a table where each flight leg is listed

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hello, suppose we have a flights table like shown on the left. Actually it contains much more data like departure time, aircraft etc but we dont need to work on them at the moment. the city "a" is the hub point. Allof the departures begin from here and turn back to here. Most of the flights are 2 leg flights.. like "a" to "b" to "a". But some of them are more than 2 legs, like "a" to "e" to "f" back to "e" and back to "a" this is a four leg flight. I'd like to create a second table with a string column and legcounts column but I am going crazy about it. I tried to make 2-3-4-5 loops, 2-3-4-5 different queries, reaching nowhere. How can I easily fill in the second table from the first one? Any help, any idea, any starting point advice is badly needed.

Comment: 1) Do you have a limit in terms of maximum number of legs to include on a path? 2) Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Sir max 4 legs. There aren't any connecting flights with more than 4 legs. Using MysQl 5x

Comment: I can do 2 seperate processes, one to find 3 legs, one to find 4 legs.

Comment: @BahadirAlkes Then `UNION` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x you can use a recursive CTE, as in:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select
    id, destination, 
    concat('-', destination, '-') as path, 1 as leg_count
  from t where departure = 'a'
 union all
  select
    t.id, t.destination, 
    concat(n.path, t.destination, '-'), n.leg_count + 1
  from n
  join t on t.departure = n.destination
        and n.leg_count < 5
        and n.destination <> 'a'
)
select concat('-a', path) as leg_str, leg_count 
from n
where destination = 'a' -- discard dangling legs
```

Result:

```
leg_str      leg_count
-----------  ---------
-a-d-a-      2
-a-c-a-      2
-a-b-a-      2
-a-e-a-      2
-a-g-h-a-    3
-a-e-f-e-a-  4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbkhoAjZacsdMZ5DqQAXJW/0).

This solution can be easily adapted to longer paths.

**EDIT for MySQL 5.x**

Now, in MySQL 5.x you can do a [rather tedious] SQL statement that joins the table multiple times for different path lenghts. As you can imagine, this solution won't scale up well for long paths:

```
select concat('a-', a.destination, '-a') as leg_str, 2 as leg_count
from t a
join t b on b.id not in (a.id) and b.departure = a.destination
where a.departure = 'a' and b.destination = 'a'
UNION ALL
select concat('a-', a.destination, '-', b.destination, '-a') as leg_str,
  3 as leg_count
from t a
join t b on b.id not in (a.id) and b.departure = a.destination
join t c on c.id not in (a.id, b.id) and c.departure = b.destination
where a.departure = 'a' and c.destination = 'a'
  and b.destination <> 'a'
UNION ALL
select concat('a-', a.destination, '-', b.destination, '-', 
  c.destination, '-a') as leg_str, 4 as leg_count
from t a
join t b on b.id not in (a.id) and b.departure = a.destination
join t c on c.id not in (a.id, b.id) and c.departure = b.destination
join t d on d.id not in (a.id, b.id, c.id) and d.departure = c.destination
where a.departure = 'a' and d.destination = 'a'
  and b.destination <> 'a' and c.destination <> 'a'
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bsi8BBLAezLxCtkobypmCL/1).

Comment: That sounds like a great code and produces exactly what i want but I dont have mySql 8 so I can't work it. Need to find a similar solution. Thank you anyway for your effort

Comment: Is there any way to convert it to a lower mySql version?

Comment: @BahadirAlkes Added a solution for MySQL 5.x. It's ugly, but works as shown by the example.

Comment: Trying right away..

Comment: The Impaler.. sir, words might not be enough to tell you how great a solution this is. It works like a charm. My table has a lot of columns and thousands of rows but, ypur code is the basis of the work that I am now going to do. Thank you very much. Wish you safe and healthy days.

Comment: The Impaler.. I'd like to thank you once again, I completed my work after 5 hours of your help, it just made my day. With my modifications to your code it took 15 lines, and I had never seen a longer SQL query before :) It works perfectly, it can easily find all connecting flights with true connections. I appreciate your effort to help me. Thank you sir.

Comment: @BahadirAlkes Glad it helped you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Badahir, you do not have enough information supplied in the first table to automatically create the data for the second table. You need to provide additional column that ties the legs with their flight.
You also may need to dynamically create the legs groups by departure/arrival time?

Comment: Ahh.. no sir, not really, all i need to find is the connecttions according to the arrival points. The Impaler has got the point and produced a perfect result table. All I need is that result.